# Is it necessary to create extra ComM channel for J1939 Dm1 message configuration?

Tags: networking, autosar, j1939

I am configuring j1939 dcm message (Dm1)using vector davinci tool.In my project all other frames follows normal can flow but only one frame following j1939 standards. I am new to j1939 and I have some doubts that
1.already I have one comM channel and is it necessary to create one more channel for j1939.
2.if dm1 message is of 8byte then how to configure it in j1939tp
3.we have both canNm and j1939 Nm how to handle both using NM.

Please any one now the solution please share your thoughts.

Comment: You should not need to create a new ComM channel, but a new ComM_User on that channel (for J1939Dcm). Not sure about your CanNm and J1939Nm though, I think, it is either one or the other, not both.